# Angular test: no manage dependencies

Tags: angular, angular-test, angular-spectator

I am new to angular 8. I wrote some components and now I am writing the tests (but spectator but its doesn't mind).

I want to write simple tests, only check that the components are created successfully.

I find dependencies management horrible, I spent 10x more times to find the required dependencies than to write the tests.

Is there really no way to avoid it? A library that could manage it for us? Or inject all dependencies by default?

Thanks.

Edit 1: the thing is that I use material, which requires a lot of dependencies. As an example of the dependencies of a component that I want to test:

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MainFormService } from 'src/app/modules/shared/services/main-form.service';
```

Comment: Can you post an example for a component you want to test, and also how long you got with the test? Without that, the only thing that can be said is that your components probably do too many things, you have to separate them into smaller ones, and those will have less dependencies.

Comment: @AlexBiro I added it to my question

Comment: Your example is not exceptional, and yes, you have to provide all those dependencies, because your code depends on them.

Answer (score 0):

If your test is shallow then you can use:

```
  schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ]
```

BUT it is not recomended to over use this! But as you said you only want to create the component. Then this should help you.

Comment: I tested it, this is the "shallow" option in the spectator component factory. However this helps but it not enough (material dependencies still required)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, however I don't know if it is a good practice or dangerous. I am surprised that no one posted it before as other people have the same problem.

Using spectator, add to the file test.ts:

```
defineGlobalsInjections({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    CommonModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ]
});
```

It should be added to the beginning of the file (otherwise it is set after tests are ran).

Comment: I don't think, that this is a good idea, because this can affect your test speed.